# How can I highlight multiple lines with Ace?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, cloud9-ide, ace-editor

The old method mentioned in similar questions here is the following:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
var Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range;
editor.setReadOnly(true);
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/github");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
editor.getSession().addMarker(new Range(1, 0, 15, 0), "ace_active_line", "background");
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, as you can see here:

http://jsbin.com/acotuv/1/edit

Any suggestions?

Comment: A small note to anyone wondering..  "ace_active_line" was changed to "ace_active-line" in a earlier release apparently.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

seems like signature of the `addMarker` function was changed

```
var Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range // get reference to ace/range
...
editor.session.addMarker(
    new Range(1, 0, 15, 0), "ace_active-line", "fullLine"
 );`
```

works fine, see http://jsbin.com/acotuv/3/edit

Comment: Note that `var Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range` in the code is necessary - took me a while to find out.

Comment: In case you are using ace together with webpack this will do it `var ace = require('brace'); var Range = ace.acequire('ace/range').Range;`

Comment: @a user Where is this documented? Over here https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=edit_session the addMarker takes four required parameters.