# Ace Editor addMarker throwing erro

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

So I have literally copied the "get started" code from ACE and then tried to add a marker. 
I copied the syntax from ACE's website which is the same as recommended here:
[How can I highlight multiple lines with Ace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024721/how-can-i-highlight-multiple-lines-with-ace)

All I get is an error in the console saying Undefined is not a function.

My goal is to add a marker so I can highlight a line of text. Any ideas why this is not working?

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
editor.getSession().addMarker(new Range(1,0,1,200),"ace_active_line","background");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to import Range

```
var Range = ace.require("ace/range").Range
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.session.addMarker(new Range(1,0,1,200),"ace_active-line","fullLine");
```

also class name for active line marker have changed.

Generally when asking questions like this it is a good idea to create a jsbin like http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/570/edit, since it helps answering a lot